# Generate variates of $F^s $ given an algorithm for $F $

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let rv $X$ have a distribution $F (t):={\rm Prob}(X <t)$ and rv $Y$ have a distribution $G (t):=(F(t))^s$ for some real constant $s\in(0,1]$.  Suppose that I know an algorithm for generating random variates of $X$. Is there a general argument/theorem, which could help me to construct an algorithm for generating the variates of $Y$ using this information?

Comment: If $s$ is positive integer, then $(F(t))^s$ is the distribution of $\max(X_1,\ldots, X_s)$, where $X_i$ are independent r.v.'s with distribution $F$. In this case you should generate $s$ times independently r.v. $X$ ant take maximal of the obtained values. I doubt that in general case there exists an algorithm to get $Y$, if we only can generate $X$.

Comment: The application requires $s$ to be real; the range can be restricted to unit interval. Appreciate the integer $s$ tip.

Comment: I updated the question